# How to use wp_nav_menu to create custom dropdown menu?

Tags: php, menus, sub-menu, dropdown

In my template I have a custom menu. Below is the HTML code for it. Inside the menu there is one dropdown menu and a link tag.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.html">Category Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="article.html">Article Page</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category Type A <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Category One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Category Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wp_nav_menu()` with proper parameters to add the `dropdown-menu forAnimate` class, to remove the wrapper and to add the `role` attribute:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="category.html">Category Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="article.html">Article Page</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category Type A <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'menu'       => 'my_menu_name', // specify the menu name
            'menu_class' => 'dropdown-menu forAnimate', // add classes for the dropdown
            'container'  => '', // don't wrap the menu in <div>
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" role="menu" >%3$s</ul>',
        ));?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`'<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" role="menu" >%3$s</ul>'` part is intended to keep `id` and `class` as is and to add the `role` attribute.

Not tested, though.

See [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) for more information.